# How to change the key of a-menu-item conditionally based on var

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, antd

I have a menuItem which needs to change the destination route based on a variable.
The variable is `var1`, and the key of menuitem should change to `key1` when `var1` is 1, `key2` when `var1` is 2.
Using antD.

```
<a-menu-item key="">
            <span>1</span>
          </a-menu-item>
```

I've tried to use `{{var1 === '1' ? '1' : '2'}}` but failed with syntax error, and I'm new to Vue hence no other solution.

Comment: ``<a-menu-item :key="`key${var1}`">``

Comment: @yoduh Thank you for your help, however the key is not equal to the var here. The clarification is that when variable UserStore equals "S", the key is personal_manage, otherwise manage.

Comment: I see.  Your attempt makes more sense then, since it's pretty close to what you want.  You used `{{ }}` which is called [text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html) and is for displaying dynamic values **between** tags as text.  You don't need to use brackets when binding values to props or attributes. `<a-menu-item :key="var1 === '1' ? '1' : '2'">`